# EMF - DC permanent magnet motor

Tags: electromagnetic, electric-machine, emf, rotor

I am using FEMM to design a DC permanent magnet rotor.

I am trying to calculate the EMF that is induced to the rotor. Since each coil has a different position, the induced EMF will be different.

In the following figure, you can see the parameters that are known for each coil.

Is it possible to calculate the induced EMF using these parameters?

If noT, how can I calculate the induced EMF in FEMM?

[image]

Comment: A "permanent magnet rotor" won't have coils and won't have an induced emf.

Comment: @Andyaka . In this topology, the permanent magnets are located in the stator and of course, there are no coils at the stator. But there are coils in the rotor.